# Add property name to an entity-based rule?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a rule like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x).Must(MatchSomething).When(x => x.Children != null)

private bool MatchSomething(Parent parent)
{
    return parent.CountOfSomething == parent.Children.Count(x => x.ChildType == ChildType.EnumValue);
}
```

The above works fine, however, with the above rule, the `PropertyName` of the `ValidationError` is empty.

Is there a way to pass a property name or do I need to change the above rule to base it on the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must() has a useful overload that I think solves your problem, which is that it can include the class you are validating as the first argument. So you can get property name to display "CountOfSomething" with the following code:

```
class ParentValidator : AbstractValidator<Parent>
{
    public ParentValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.CountOfSomething).Must(MatchSomething).When(x => x.Children != null);
    }

    private bool MatchSomething(Parent parent, int countOfSomething)
    {
        return countOfSomething == parent.Children.Count(x => x.ChildType == ChildType.EnumValue);
    }
}
```

I don't know a way of passing "CountOfSomething" as a parameter, but the above is hopefully a pretty quick code fix!